# Login to a website (billboard.com) for scraping purposes using R, when the login is done through a pop-up window

Tags: r, selenium, authentication, form-submit, rselenium

I want to **scrape** some "pro" billboard data, which access requires a premium billboard account. I already have one, but obvisouly I need to login to the billboard website through R in order to be able to **scrape** this data.
I have no issues with such a thing with regular login pages (for instance, stackoverflow):

```
##### Stackoverflow login #####
# Packages installation and loading ---------------------------------------

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(rvest,dplyr,tidyr)
packages<-c("rvest","dplyr","tidyr")
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)


#Address of the login webpage
login_test<-"https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

#create a web session with the desired login address
pgsession_test<-html_session(login_test)
pgform_test<-html_form(pgsession_test)[[2]]  #in this case the submit is the 2nd form
filled_form_test<-set_values(pgform_test, email="myemail", password="mypassword")

filled_form_test$fields[[5]]$type <- "button"

submit_form(pgsession_test, filled_form_test)
```

The issue with the billboard website is that the login is done through a clickable "sign up" button in the header of the page, which trigger a pop-up window allowing to type in an email address and password, thus allowing the user to login.
So far, I've tried to guess where the login form is in the html output of the billboard page, as it is not obvious, but I don't even think it actually appears, and I think scraping the html code from pop-up windows might require a specific process.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
##### Billboard scraping #####
# Packages installation and loading ---------------------------------------

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(rvest,dplyr,tidyr)
packages<-c("rvest","dplyr","tidyr")
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)



# Session setup (required to scrape restricted access web pages) -----------
login<-"https://www.billboard.com/myaccount"

#create a web session with the desired login address
pgsession<-html_session(login)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]  
pgform$fields[[2]]$value <- 'myemailaddress'
pgform$fields[[1]]$value <- 'mypassword'




filled_form<-set_values(pgform)

fake_submit_button <- list(name = NULL,
                           type = "submit",
                           value = NULL,
                           checked = NULL,
                           disabled = NULL,
                           readonly = NULL,
                           required = FALSE)
attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "input"
filled_form[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button

# filled_form$fields[[3]]$type <- "button"
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

The returned error is :

```
Warning message:
In request_GET(session, url = url, query = request$values, ...) :
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

Which I understand as simply the result of me not using the right login form, that I also suspect not be available in my html output (given by `pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]` in the code above).
Note that I've also tried with `pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Also, if anybody could at least tell me if the solution has something to do with RSelenium, that would be great.

Comment: Did you try to use Rselenium? Could you provide the website?

Comment: I haven't tried Rselenium yet, is it the way to go?  
The website is https://www.billboard.com/

Comment: Okay, I will write a possible solution. Give me a bit time. ;)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm really sorry but my solution doesn't work and I can't share it.
Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Alright, no problem. Do you know if it's doable with Rselenium anyway?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I suggest you to add a new two tags at your question `Rselenium` and `Selenium`

Comment: Thanks you for your help.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap